# From TextIOWrapper to parse in Biopython

Tags: python, dictionary, biopython

I wrote a script and create a multiple alignment fasta using a loop and store it in a file.

```
concatenation = open ('example.fasta', 'w')
for key, value in concat.items():
    output = '>' + key + '\n' + value + '\n'
    concatenation.write(output)
```

I want to use the function of AlignIO to convert my fasta into phylip (and open a new file), but I am not able to find a way to parse my 'example.fasta'.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert a biopython fasta alignment to phylip, you can simply use the `convert` method.

```
from Bio import AlignIO

AlignIO.convert("myFastaInputFile","fasta","myPhylipOutFile","phylip")
```

If you need to read the alignment from file first, you can use `parse` and then convert:

```
myAlignment = AlignIO.parse("myFastaAlignment","fasta")
```